# Altering UI colour within ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table-of-contents, user-interface

I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to change the colours of the user interface within ArcMap?

Specifically the background and text colours of the table of contents and the ArcCatalog/Toolbox Windows etc.

I've done some of my own extensive searching online as well as searching through the questions here on the site and haven't found anything helpful relating to it.

So me educated guess would be that it's not possible but I still wanted to get a definitive answer either way.

Answer (score 6):

ArcMap takes color and font settings from the Windows theme, so strictly speaking, you *can* change those. It's a system wide setting, though. I included a screenshot from ArcMap with the High Contrast theme included with Windows 8.1.

[image: ArcMap with the High Contrast theme]

If you want to change ArcMap only, then it would need to be programmed (if you're a developer yourself, search for 'intercept wndproc').